# Calculate mean per few columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

I have a Pandas dataframe, Data:

```
ID | A1| A2| B1| B2 
ID1| 2 | 1 | 3 | 7 
ID2| 4 | 6 | 5 | 3
```

I want to calculate mean of columns (A1 and A2), and (B1 and B2) separately and row-wise . My desired output:

```
ID | A1A2 mean | B1B2 mean
ID1| 1.5       | 5
ID2| 5         | 4
```

I can do mean of all columns together , but cannot find any functions to get my desired output.
Is there any built-in method in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function for get first letter of columns for `mean`, also if first column is not index use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df=df.set_index('ID').groupby(lambda x: x[0], axis=1).mean().add_suffix('_mean').reset_index()
print (df)
    ID  A_mean  B_mean
0  ID1     1.5     5.0
1  ID2     5.0     4.0
```

Another solution is extract columns names by indexing `str[0]`:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')

print (df.columns.str[0])
Index(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], dtype='object')

df = df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).mean().add_suffix('_mean').reset_index()
print (df)
    ID  A_mean  B_mean
0  ID1     1.5     5.0
1  ID2     5.0     4.0
```

Or:

```
df = (df.set_index('ID')
        .groupby(df.columns[1:].str[0], axis=1)
        .mean()
        .add_suffix('_mean').reset_index()
```

Verify solution:

```
a = df.filter(like='A').mean(axis=1)
b = df.filter(like='B').mean(axis=1)

df = df[['ID']].assign(A_mean=a, B_mean=b)
print (df)
    ID  A_mean  B_mean
0  ID1     1.5     5.0
1  ID2     5.0     4.0
```

EDIT:

If have different columns names and need specify them in lists:

```
a = df[['A1','A2']].mean(axis=1)
b = df[['B1','B2']].mean(axis=1)

df = df[['ID']].assign(A_mean=a, B_mean=b)
print (df)
```

Comment: what is x here? Actually I need to calculate mean of two columns separately

Comment: It will calculate a single mean for all columns. But I need to calculate mean of a1 and a2 together, and b1 and b2 together

Comment: It calculates mean of all columns like before. Here I have 4 columns, and need to calculate mean of a1 and a2; mean of b1 and b2. I apply your technique which calculates mean of a1,a2,b1,b2

Comment: if you group by by columns.str[0], the problem will be if columns names are totally different name from each other

Comment: your technique is excellent. But my real column names are different and different length. E.g. "sal 1", "second salary", "old salary", "payment 2010". How I calculate mean between  "sal 1" and "second salary"; and separately "old salary" and "payment 2010"?

Comment: df[['A1','A2']].mean(axis=1) works fine which calculates mean of these two columns. BUT df[['A1','A2'] ['B1', 'B2']].mean(axis=1) does not work which shows error

Comment: @studentcoder - If need mean of more columns, use `df[['A1','A2', 'B1', 'B2']].mean(axis=1)`

Comment: Your last edit works! Excellent way! Thanks a lot ! But I thought it should have some straight way like SELECT SQL technique